# Smart array P212 error code 727

Tags: linux, raid, hardware-raid, hp-smart-array, hpe

We recently purchased HP DL380P GEN8 server and D3700 enclosure with 20TB of disks.

I  wanted to connect both servers with Smart Array P212 but I encountered and error once I tried to configure the RAID from the server :

Here is the message error:

[image]

I tried to google it but nothing come out

kindly someone guide me to solve my problem

Comment: The [P212 manual](https://www.hpe.com/psnow/doc/c04111625) states *"The SA-P212 Controller supports the HP D2600 Disk Enclosure, HP D2700 Disk Enclosure, and the
HP 600 Modular Disk System"*  which suggests  that a D3700 is not supported

Comment: Always check the support matrix when purchasing hardware that is over 10 years old.

Comment: Isn't gen8 already EOL? which. make already it off topic?